# Lightning: why don't balances add up to capacity?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-rfc

I've created a brand new lightning channel with two nodes.

I loaded the channel with `"capacity": "1000000"`, but `"local_balance": "999056"`. I know that `"commit_fee": "614"` accounts for some reserved sats for channel closing. But that still leaves about 330 sats unaccounted for. Where are these sats visible? Thanks

```
"channels": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "remote_pubkey": "0340b6591708a3bc385aef0c69e6e618e5e3de0f66d923607f55ea035b71dedd47",
            "channel_point": "6ac2d8f922b0d1f2d5de39d2819777cb8bc40b6d8f6226211bbba34eada55965:1",
            "chan_id": "2582377880184815617",
            "capacity": "1000000",
            "local_balance": "999056",
            "remote_balance": "0",
            "commit_fee": "614",
            "commit_weight": "772",
            "fee_per_kw": "253",
            "unsettled_balance": "0",
            "total_satoshis_sent": "0",
            "total_satoshis_received": "0",
            "num_updates": "0",
            "pending_htlcs": [
            ],
            "csv_delay": 144,
            "private": false,
            "initiator": true,
            "chan_status_flags": "ChanStatusDefault",
            "local_chan_reserve_sat": "10000",
            "remote_chan_reserve_sat": "10000",
            "static_remote_key": false,
            "commitment_type": "ANCHORS",
            "lifetime": "24",
            "uptime": "24",
            "close_address": "",
            "push_amount_sat": "0",
            "thaw_height": 0,
            "local_constraints": {
                "csv_delay": 144,
                "chan_reserve_sat": "10000",
                "dust_limit_sat": "573",
                "max_pending_amt_msat": "990000000",
                "min_htlc_msat": "1",
                "max_accepted_htlcs": 483
            },
            "remote_constraints": {
                "csv_delay": 144,
                "chan_reserve_sat": "10000",
                "dust_limit_sat": "573",
                "max_pending_amt_msat": "990000000",
                "min_htlc_msat": "1",
                "max_accepted_htlcs": 483
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that still leaves about 330 sats unaccounted for

You are probably missing the [anchor output](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/03-transactions.md#to_local_anchor-and-to_remote_anchor-output-option_anchors) contained in the commitment transaction in your calculation. Its value is exactly 330 sats.

---

*Note: this answer previously incorrectly assumed it was due to the reserve not being part of the balance. It was entirely re-written.*

Comment: "This is called the reserve. Your node will not show you the reserve as part of your balance (since you can't spend it)." This part is a bit confusing. My local balance shows 999056, but my local_chan_reserve_sat is 10000. My local balance is not missing 10k sats from capacity, only less than 1k sats.

Comment: Hmmm right. I'm wrong, the reserve appears to be part of your balance here. Maybe you just made a mistake in computing transaction fees. I'll delete my answer to not mislead anyone else.

Comment: Oh, you probably just forgot to account for the anchor output! I'll update my answer instead.